# How to prove a sequence of random variables dependent on different random variables is a homogeneous Markov chain?

Tags: markov-process, transition-matrix

In Pierre Brémaud's book, *Markov Chains - Gibbs Fields, Monte Carlo Simulation and Queues*, exercise 2.6.9 is stated as follows:

> Let $\{Z_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ be an IID sequence of geometric random variables: for k $\geq$ 0, $\mathbb{P}(Z_n = k) = (1 - p)^kp$, where $p \in (0,1)$. Let $X_n = \max(Z_1, ..., Z_n)$ be the record value at time $n$, and suppose $X_0$ is a $\mathbb{N}$-valued random variable independent of the sequence $\{Z_n\}_{n \geq 1}$. Show that $\{X_n\}_{n \geq 0}$ is a homogeneous Markov Chain and give its transition matrix.

Given $k \geq 0$, we can understand $Z_n$ as the probability distribution of the number of failures before the first success in a sequence of trials.

I also know that, given $X_0$ is a $\mathbb{N}$-value random variable, $X_n$ can be written as:

$$\{X_n\}_{n \geq 0} = (X_0, \max(Z_1), \max(Z_1, Z_2), ... ,\max(Z_1, ..., Z_n))$$

[I found this question here on Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/386725/proving-that-given-markov-chain-is-homogeneous-find-state-space-and-transition) and tried using its answer to guide my reasoning. So, in similar fashion, I tried

- State space - Given $Xn$ can only take values in $\mathbb{N}$, the state space $E$ is the set of natural numbers.
- Transition - Here, I should ask myself how ${X_n}$ evolves with time. I know that, with every new value $Z_n$, there is a new (yet possibly repeated) value for $X_n$. However, here I faced my first obstacle. I don't know to express a transition from state $i$ to state $j$ with the given information. I know that $X_n \xrightarrow{} X_{n+1}$ means $X_{n+1} = \max(Z_1, Z_2, ..., Z_{n+1})$. But all I can say about the behavior of $Z_n$ is expressed by its probability distribution. The beginning of a sequence migh look like $(Z_1, Z_2, Z_3, ...) = (\mathbb{P}(Z_1 = 2), \mathbb{P}(Z_2 = 0), \mathbb{P}(Z_3 = 1) = ((1-p)^2p, \ p, \ (1-p)p, ...)$.

I don't see any pattern in this, and don't know how to proceed. Without this information, I can't establish probabilities, let alone build the transition matrix. I'd imagine that if I had a finite  state space, this could be easier to understand (yet I'm not sure of that).

If anyone could help and show me what steps I should/could take next, I'd appreciate it.